# I am trying to remove cookies in reactjs but it does not get removed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I have a following function to remove cookies in reactjs app.

```
onLogout = () => {
    document.cookie = 'token= ; expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT';
    document.cookie = 'userID= ; expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT';
    document.cookie = 'role= ; expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT';
    
    return <Redirect to='/login' />
  }
```

It sets the expires to past time to remove cookies. But when I open google chrome tools and checking the cookies it does not remove them when I click on logout button. And it does not gets redirected to login route as well. However, when I refresh browser then the cookies are removed.

Any idea where am I making mistake and how to fix this?

Here is jsx for button.

```
<button onClick={this.onLogout}>Logout</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```js
onLogout = () => {
  const cExpire = new Date(0).toUTCString()
  document.cookie = $ `token=; expires=${cExpire}`;
  document.cookie = $ `userID=; expires=${cExpire}`;
  document.cookie = $ `role=; expires=${cExpire}`;

  return <Redirect to = '/login' / >
}
```